# Accessing methods from module in resque job

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, resque

Hi I have to access a method from a module in a resuq job, I keep getting this error: method not accessible. Am I using the module incorrectly??

```
class TestResqueJob
 include TestModule
 @queue = :test_resque

 def self.perform(params)
  method_from_module
 end 
end 

module TestModule
  def method_from_module
    puts "test"
  end 
end
```

Comment: could you share the module code please?

Comment: @Kkulikovskis, I have shared the module code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to call an instance method inside a public method. I f you want your module methods to be class methods change `include` to `extend`

```
class TestResqueJob
 extend TestModule
 @queue = :test_resque

 def self.perform(params)
  method_from_module
 end 
end
```

this will make all the methods you have defined in the module as class methods